# Preformatted text is insufficiently distinct?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The background used for answers on askubuntu.com is slightly grey; this makes preformatted text such as `this` stand out significantly less than on, say stackoverflow.com.

I think this requires a design change to make such text a little bit more distinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

I have darkened the background color to #CCC as Mat suggested. Should be in the next deployment.

Comment: The new coloring looks great!

Comment: Yup.  That's much better.

Comment: I think it may be too dark now - e.g. on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12302/switching-buffers-in-vim it makes it quite difficult to read... I think #DDD would look better, personally (I don't know what it was originally).

Answer (score 0):

Well let's see -- this is a code block:

```
foreach foo in bar
next
```

and this is a `code span` in text

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I think we can make the bg a bit darker.

I think we can go even as dark as #CCCCCC