# Links in <code> spans are indistinguishable from normal <code> spans

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here's the real life example that triggered this:

> Make sure you check for duplicates before adding new entries. For example, [search `pitivi inquestion:this`](http://#) before adding PiTiVi. :)

Comment: That's a dummy link that goes nowhere, stop clicking :)

Comment: This is a dup of http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/451/preformatted-text-is-insufficiently-distinct

Comment: @andrew: no, this is about <a href="blah"><code>foo</code></a>

Comment: i believe this has been fixed now. same issue as http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/738/make-links-visible-on-escaped-text

Comment: @Jin It has indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

I have darkened the pre/code blocks' bgcolor to #CCC. Will be in the next deployment.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, the issue is [`<a href="blah"><code>foo</code></a>`](http://#) is visually indistinguishable from `<code>foo</code>`.