# Make links visible on escaped text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, css, hyperlinks

There is no visible difference between [`AskUbuntu`](http://askubuntu.com) and `AskUbuntu`, even though the first occurence points to [a link](http://askubuntu.com) and the second doesn't.

It could be argued that it is not necessary, but stackoverflow.com gives a different color to escaped text with a link - and I think following their behaviour would be good.

Adding these rules should do the trick (StackOverflow does not have to add such rules because it does not override the color in a `code` block):

```
a code{color:#07c;}
a:visited code{color:#4A6B82;}
```

Comment: I'll put in a fix for this in the next deployment.

Comment: Looks to me like this has been fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.